# Is it possible to chain two vpn ( l2tp ) connections?

Tags: networking, vpn, nat, windows-server, l2tp

I have three computers, A, B, C (I installed windows server 2019 on them).

PC C has access to the webpage D, PC A and B do not.

I first dialed a vpn connection (l2tp) from A to B, then I dialed a vpn connection from B to C.

I found out that it's possible for applications on pc B to access webpage D, but it's not possible for applications on PC A to access webpage D[image].

Why is this, and what should I do to make it possible for network traffic to pass through these two vpn connections? It's theoretically possible isn't it?

**I have to keep this topology, I can't change it.**

I tried ping 8.8.8.8 in **pc A**, this what i captured with wireshark in pc B ,
[image]

these packets are found in pc B, but no response .

I tried ping 8.8.8.8 in **pc B**, this what i captured with wireshark in pc B ,
[image]

these packets are found in pc B, and there're responses .

Comment: You are looking to implement what is called VPN Chaining or Double VPN, Doublehop VPN or Multihop VPN.  This is complex to manage.  Depending what/why you could simply run a VM on PC B and use that when you connect from A.  Probably worth looking at [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and providing some detail around the why.

Comment: Just to check, Are all the IP subnets these systems are on unique for all systems in the diagram, and do all systems only have routes to the networks on the diagram for each of those ranges? if there are any overlaps or if one of the systems is connected to an unrelated network that overlaps with one of the networks in the diagram, then what you want can't work.

Comment: @BlindSpots ,basically ,I bought an vpn software ,and i want to share this vpn connection among multiple clients without cracking this software .

Comment: @FrankThomas that may be the problem ,in my TEST case , all three computres are in the same subnet 192.168.1.0/24, so i should move them to three different subnets are test again .

Comment: @iouvxz nothing in what you described equates to VPN Chaining/Double VPN.  Either it is unnecessary or there remains a *why* that you haven't shared. See [The XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @BlindSpots, (1) I need to share this vpn connection across the internet ,(2) all my applications are third party and (3) don't have a built-in proxy setting .I thought VPN Chaining should be suffice , what's your suggestion then ?

Comment: So PC A connects to PC B with a public IP address, and PC B connects to PC with a public IP address?  And Webpage D = any public webpage?

Comment: anyway ,I have conrol over these subnets ,so you can assume pc A ,B ,C have public addresses .webpage D is just for testing purpose, my ultimate goal is to farm gold in a game without showing my true ip address ,this game doesn't support proxy or anything .

Comment: @FrankThomas I set these computers to 3 different subnet (192.168.1.0/24,192.168.2.0/24,192.168.3.0/24) ,and this phenomenon persists, still can't access internet after dailing two consecutive vpn connections .

Comment: are your routes lining up so that each systems route to 0.0.0.0 is using the VPN adapter as its exit interface and its IP address as the remote tunnel IP?

Comment: @FrankThomas yes, each system route 0.0.0.0 to the vpn adapter . does "the remote tunnel IP" means the destination ip of the vpn connection, if so ,yes .